# Image upload from local computer in wysiwyg

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce, wysiwyg

What´s the best way how can I add image upload from local computer to TinyMCE? I found [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce) but it is just for drupal or not? I need solution which will work with asp.net MVC3. Then I found this [TinySLUpload](http://tinyslupload.codeplex.com/) but I want solution without silverlight. What´s my options and which is the best?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**!!!!ENJOY!!! here is the solution to load directly from local computer**

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1ad17co9/)

```
`tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea",
toolbar: "mybutton",
height:400,
setup: function(editor) {
    editor.addButton('mybutton', {
        text:"IMAGE",
        icon: false,
        onclick: function(e) {
            console.log($(e.target));
            if($(e.target).prop("tagName") == 'BUTTON'){
            console.log($(e.target).parent().parent().find('input').attr('id'));                    if($(e.target).parent().parent().find('input').attr('id') != 'tinymce-uploader') {
            $(e.target).parent().parent().append('<input id="tinymce-uploader" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" style="display:none">');
                }
            $('#tinymce-uploader').trigger('click');
            $('#tinymce-uploader').change(function(){
             var input, file, fr, img;

        if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
            write("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
            return;
        }

        input = document.getElementById('tinymce-uploader');
        if (!input) {
            write("Um, couldn't find the imgfile element.");
        }
        else if (!input.files) {
            write("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
        }
        else if (!input.files[0]) {
            write("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
        }
        else {
            file = input.files[0];
            fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = createImage;
            fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        }

        function createImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.src = fr.result;
             editor.insertContent('<img src="'+img.src+'"/>');

        }

            });

        }
        if($(e.target).prop("tagName") == 'DIV'){
        if($(e.target).parent().find('input').attr('id') != 'tinymce-uploader') {
        console.log($(e.target).parent().find('input').attr('id'));                                
            $(e.target).parent().append('<input id="tinymce-uploader" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" style="display:none">');
                         }
            $('#tinymce-uploader').trigger('click');
            $('#tinymce-uploader').change(function(){
             var input, file, fr, img;

        if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
            write("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
            return;
        }

        input = document.getElementById('tinymce-uploader');
        if (!input) {
            write("Um, couldn't find the imgfile element.");
        }
        else if (!input.files) {
            write("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
        }
        else if (!input.files[0]) {
            write("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
        }
        else {
            file = input.files[0];
            fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = createImage;
            fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        }

        function createImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.src = fr.result;
             editor.insertContent('<img src="'+img.src+'"/>');

        }

            });

        }
        if($(e.target).prop("tagName") == 'I'){
        console.log($(e.target).parent().parent().parent().find('input').attr('id')); if($(e.target).parent().parent().parent().find('input').attr('id') != 'tinymce-uploader') {               $(e.target).parent().parent().parent().append('<input id="tinymce-uploader" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" style="display:none">');
                                                                                       }
            $('#tinymce-uploader').trigger('click');
            $('#tinymce-uploader').change(function(){
             var input, file, fr, img;

        if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
            write("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
            return;
        }

        input = document.getElementById('tinymce-uploader');
        if (!input) {
            write("Um, couldn't find the imgfile element.");
        }
        else if (!input.files) {
            write("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
        }
        else if (!input.files[0]) {
            write("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
        }
        else {
            file = input.files[0];
            fr = new FileReader();
            fr.onload = createImage;
            fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        }

        function createImage() {
            img = new Image();
            img.src = fr.result;
             editor.insertContent('<img src="'+img.src+'"/>');

        }

            });

        }

        }
    });
}});
```

`

Answer (score 1):

The above solution for uploading image directly on TinyMCE was great and in fact it works on my end perfectly. Just little issue on *insertContent*, it doesn't show image on my part so I did a little change. Instead of using *insertContent* replace it using *editor.dom.create* and *editor.selection.setNode(image)* to add image element. And don't forget to unbind the *change event* to avoid multiple binding that may cause to duplicate newly uploaded image depends on how many image you already uploaded.

```
setup: function (editor) {
            editor.addButton('mybutton', {
                text: "Image",
                icon: false,
                onclick: function (e) {
                    if ($(e.target).prop("tagName") == 'BUTTON') {
                        if ($(e.target).parent().parent().find('input').attr('id') != 'tinymce-uploader') {
                            $(e.target).parent().parent().append('<input id="tinymce-uploader" type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*" style="display:none">');
                        }

                        $('#tinymce-uploader').trigger('click');

                        $('#tinymce-uploader').change(changeImage);

                        function changeImage () {
                            var input, file, fr, img;

                            if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
                                write("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
                                return;
                            }

                            input = document.getElementById('tinymce-uploader');
                            if (!input) {
                                write("Um, couldn't find the imgfile element.");
                            }
                            else if (!input.files) {
                                write("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
                            }
                            else if (!input.files[0]) {
                                write("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
                            }
                            else {
                                file = input.files[0];
                                fr = new FileReader();
                                fr.onload = createImage;
                                fr.readAsDataURL(file);
                            }

                            function createImage() {
                                img = new Image();
                                img.src = fr.result;                                    
                                var image = editor.dom.create('img', { src: img.src }, "");
                                editor.selection.setNode(image);

                            }
                            $('#tinymce-uploader').unbind("change", changeImage);
                        }

                    }                    

                }
            });
        }
```