# How do I add a file uploading feature to tinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, html, image, file-upload, tinymce

I am currently using tinyMCE for my website. I want to be able to browse folders on my computer to upload images. When I click on insert/edit image, it shows a button to browse files, but when I try to click on it, nothing happens. Does anybody know how to fix this so I can easily upload images?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        plugins: [
                "advlist autolink autosave link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak spellchecker",
                "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
                "table contextmenu directionality emoticons template textcolor paste fullpage textcolor",
        ],

        toolbar1: "newdocument fullpage | bold italic underline strikethrough | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | styleselect formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect",
        toolbar2: "cut copy paste | searchreplace | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | undo redo | link unlink anchor image media code | inserttime preview | forecolor backcolor",
        toolbar3: "table | hr removeformat | subscript superscript | charmap emoticons | print fullscreen | ltr rtl | spellchecker | visualchars visualblocks nonbreaking template pagebreak restoredraft",

        menubar: false,
        toolbar_items_size: 'small',
        image_advtab: true,
        file_browser_callback : 'myFileBrowser',

        style_formats: [
                {title: 'Bold text', inline: 'b'},
                {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
                {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
                {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
                {title: 'Table styles'},
                {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'}
        ],

        templates: [
                {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
                {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
        ]
});</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure nothing actually happened? Instead of, you know, just taking awhile to happen?

Comment: Yes I am sure. I think it is because I do not have a proper plugin for file uploads. Would that be it?

Comment: Perhaps. I don't use TinyMCE myself. But from what I've seen on their example on their website, it does take some times for it to appear. I'll try it real quick.

Comment: Uh... do you happen to be using moxiemanager?

Comment: No, I am not. Is that a plugin that costs money? If it costs money is there another free alternative? If it is not, how do I install it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does cost money. I'm not aware of a free alternative, other that by writing it yourself. The <input type="file"> tag could do this, but it needs a way to be invoked at will, and that involves javascript, which means cross-browser problems.... Try looking at jQuery's docs and see whether they have an easy solution for this.

Comment: Thank you for all of your help with this. I really appreciate it.

Comment: please look this post for your answer [look here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601068/image-upload-from-local-computer-in-wysiwyg/26732460#26732460